# The minCompileSdk (31) specified

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

```
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30). Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha02. AAR metadata file: C:\Users\mohammad.zeeshan1.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a20beb0771f59a8ddbbb8d416ea06a9d\jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0-alpha02\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

Comment: Are you using one signal dependancy in your project?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line of code in-app `build.gradle file.

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
    }
```

Comment: didn't worked! Sorry

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the error message, if you use `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha02`, your `compileSdk` needs to be at least `31` and you have `30` there.

Either update the compile SDK version or use an older version of the core-ktx dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Change **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to 31 in build.gradle(app)

```js
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // <-- HERE
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.package"
        targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- AND HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I do in the vent that I want to use a lower targetSDK?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here,
in my case solved it by changing

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

if you don't want to downgrade, you can upgrade the compile and targetSdkVersion to 31 as @Hardik Hirpara mention

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the **compileSdk** to **31** and **targetSdk** to **31**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).