# Android : How can I know what dependency require a certain mincompileapk?

Tags: android, gradle

So I had this issue
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).

which is answered here :
[The minCompileSdk (31) specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69097847/the-mincompilesdk-31-specified)

**My question is :** how could I have known which dependency brought this issue ? How did the user laalto knew it was android core ?

I tried looking at https://mvnrepository.com/
but it does not talk about any mincompile version :
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.core/core-ktx/1.7.0-beta01

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compile error should tell you the dependency that is causing the issue. In Android Studio, check right hand side of the build tab. In my case I found it was `androidx.core:core-ktx` because the compiler gave this error:

```
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-beta01.
AAR metadata file: /Users/XX/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/XX/jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0-beta01/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

The `BETA` jumped out at me straight away. Double check your gradle.build files. The error is likely caused by an ambiguous version specification of a library that your project implements. A new version is probably being used that requires a higher minimum compile version. After checking build.gradle files for all my modules, I found that I had included the following in one of my modules:

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

I checked the [Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) and found that the latest stable release was actually 1.6.0. After changing the line above to specify the stable release, it solved my problem, ie:

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

Keeping all of your dependencies up to date is important, but I would rather manually manage these to prevent issues like this rather than letting the compiler use unstable versions or versions that require a higher minimum compile target, for example.